# How to write ternary operator inside laravelcollective form tags

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I am using laravelcollective in blade template to define forms and facing the following issue. If i am using HTML in balde template it's working fine.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>;
```

**LaravelCollective:**

```
{!! Form::text('email', null, [ 
     'class' => "form-control  ($errors->has('email')) ? ' is-invalid' : ''", 
     'placeholder' => 'Email', 
     'required' => 'required' 
]) !!}
```

The above line is not parsed properly. It's parsed like below.

**Parsed Output of LaravelCollective**

```
<input class="form-control  ([]('email')) ? ' is-invalid' : ' '  " placeholder="Email" required="required" name="email" type="text">;
```

Comment: `"form-control  ".($errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '')` should work.

Comment: Thank you apokryfos. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple syntax error , ***)***

```
{!! Form::text('email', null, [ 
     'class' => "form-control  ($errors->has('email')) ? ' is-invalid' : '')", 
     'placeholder' => 'Email', 
     'required' => 'required' 
]) !!}
```

Sorry @apokryfos tell you! sorry !